# INSERT into SQL Server Tables Using JOIN and Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to create a `Students` table, a `Students_Images` table and a `Photo_Collection` table. Image paths are stored in `Student_Images`, each image is linked to a `Photo_Collection` row, and each `Photo_Collection` is related to a `Student` row.

The Student records will already exist. Then a student can create a Photo Collection for themselves, and add photos to this Photo Collection. So each image will need to be associated with a Photo Collection, and each Photo Collection associated with a Student.

I was told to use the below code:

```
create table dbo.Students
(
  ID
    int not null identity( 1, 1 )
    constraint [Students.ID.PrimaryKey]
      primary key clustered,

  Name
    nvarchar( 50 )
)

create table dbo.Student_Images
(
  ID
    int not null identity( 1, 1 )
    constraint [Student_Images.ID.PrimaryKey]
      primary key clustered,

  Student_ID
    int not null
    constraint [Student_Images.to.Student]
      foreign key references dbo.Students( ID )

  Filename
    nvarchar( 250 ) null,

  Description
    nvarchar( 250 ) null
)

create table dbo.Photo_Collection
(
  ID
    int not null identity( 1, 1 )
    constraint [Photo_Collection.ID.PrimaryKey]
      primary key clustered,

  Name
    nvarchar( 250 ) null
)

create table dbo.Photo_Collection_Images
(
  Photo_Collection_ID
    int not null
    constraint [Photo_Collection_Images.to.Photo_Collection]
      foreign key references dbo.Photo_Collection( ID ),

  Student_Image_ID
    int not null
    constraint [Photo_Collection_Images.to.Student_Images]
      foreign key references dbo.Student_Images( ID )
)
```

Below is an example of how these tables would look when populated:

[image: snip1]

I can `INSERT into Students,` `Student_Images` and `Photo_Collection` using the following SQL:

```
protected void btnAddImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    addImage();
}

public void addStudent()
{
    string cmdText = "INSERT INTO Students (Name) VALUES (@N)";

    //====== Providning information to SQL command object about which query to 
    //====== execute and from where to get database connection information.
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);

    //===== Adding parameters/Values.
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N", txtStudentName.Text.ToString());
    //===== To check current state of the connection object. If it is closed open the connection
    //===== to execute the insert query.
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
    }

    //===== Execute Query.
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //===== close the connection.
    con.Close();
}

public void addCollection()
{
    string cmdText = "INSERT INTO Photo_Collection (Name) VALUES (@N)";

    //====== Providning information to SQL command object about which query to 
    //====== execute and from where to get database connection information.
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);

    //===== Adding parameters/Values.
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N", txtPhotoCollectionName.Text.ToString());
    //===== To check current state of the connection object. If it is closed open the connection
    //===== to execute the insert query.
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
    }

    //===== Execute Query.
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //===== close the connection.
    con.Close();
}

public void addImage()
{
    string cmdText = "INSERT INTO Student_Images (Student_Id, Filename, Description) VALUES (@S, @F, @D)";

    //====== Providning information to SQL command object about which query to 
    //====== execute and from where to get database connection information.
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);

    //===== Adding parameters/Values.
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S", ddlStudentNames.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@F", fuImage.FileName.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@D", txtImageDescription.Text.ToString());


    //===== To check current state of the connection object. If it is closed open the connection
    //===== to execute the insert query.
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
    }

    //===== Execute Query.
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //===== close the connection.
    con.Close();
}
protected void btnAddStudentAndCollection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    addStudent();
    addCollection();
}
```

}

I need to retrieve from the database, something like this:

[image: snip]

But I don't know how to `INSERT` and `SELECT` using the `Photo_Collection_Images` table because I don't know how to reference the foreign key's I need in order to link the tables together.

Can anyone tell me how to successfully create a photo collection and add an image to it?

The reason I am finding this difficult is because I have to join a number of tables.

Comment: You don't have to worry.  Once the database tables are configured the data base will automatically look up the foreign keys.  The database does the mapping using the columns in your insert statement.  When adding/inserting you have to make sure the Primary Key Column is not null.

Comment: @jdweng So are you saying that after the  `INSERT INTO Student` and `INSERT INTO Student_Images` statements, the PK's of both of these rows will be added to the Photo_Collection_Images table?

Comment: @jdweng I have posted my INSERT statements above, they are inserting correctly into Student, Student_Images and Photo_Collection, but nothing is being inserted into Photo_Collection_Images at the moment

Comment: If you are going what you say in the first paragraph then don't do that.  That is defining the same relationship twice.

Comment: @Paparazzi Hi, What would you advise me to do?

Comment: Fix the data design.  Two mean say they are Jesus one of them must be wrong.

Comment: @Paparazzi All I want is the to display output like the drawing I posted above. I want a **student** linked to  a **Photo_Collection** and a **Photo_Collection** linked to **Images**. So to display the Photo_Collections (containing images), linked to the Student

Comment: You might to take a peek at this article - http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To insert images into a collection without knowing the ids yet.

```
/* insert without knowing the ids yet */

insert into Photo_Collection_Images (Photo_Collection_Id , Student_Image_Id)
select pc.Id, si.Id
from dbo.photo_collection as pc 
  inner join dbo.student_images as si on pc.student_id = si.student_id
  inner join dbo.students as s on s.id=si.student_id
where s.Name = @S -- student_name
  and pc.Name = @PC -- photo_collection.name
  and si.FileName = @F -- student_images.filename
```

To get all collections for a student:

```
/* all collections for one student*/
select pc.Name, si.Id, si.filename, si.description
from dbo.photo_collection as pc
inner join dbo.photo_collection_images pci on pc.id = pci.photo_collection_id
inner join dbo.student_images si on pci.student_image_id = si.id
where si.student_id = @s
-- and pc.name = @N /* one collection */
```

And about your question concerning table order, this is the same as the previous query:

```
/* all collections for one student*/
select pc.Name, si.Id, si.filename, si.description
from dbo.student_images as si 
inner join dbo.photo_collection_images pci on pci.student_image_id = si.id
inner join dbo.photo_collection as pc on pc.id = pci.photo_collection_id
where si.student_id = @s
-- and pc.name = @N /* one collection */
```

To get all collections for a student by name:

```
/* all collections for one student*/
select pc.Name, si.Id, si.filename, si.description
from dbo.student as s 
inner join dbo.student_images as si on s.id = si.student_id
inner join dbo.photo_collection_images pci on pci.student_image_id = si.id
inner join dbo.photo_collection as pc on pc.id = pci.photo_collection_id
where s.Name = @s
-- and pc.name = @N /* one collection */
```

To get all collections for all students

```
/* all collections for all students */
select student_name = s.name, pc.Name, si.Id, si.filename, si.description
from dbo.student as s 
inner join dbo.student_images as si on s.id = si.student_id
inner join dbo.photo_collection_images pci on pci.student_image_id = si.id 
inner join dbo.photo_collection as pc on pc.id = pci.photo_collection_id
```

Comment: @StephanLechner Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood you right, but consider the following query.
It gives you for every student the list of his images and the collections in which they occur. 
When ordering the result by student name and photo collection name, then your code that iterates over the result would just have to watch whenever photo collection name or student name changes in order to start a new "group" in the interface.

Hope it helps.

```
select s.*, pc.name, si.filename, si.description  from student s
  left outer join student_images si on s.id = si.student_id
  left outer join photo_collection_images pci on pci.student_image_id = si.id
  left outer join photo_collection pc on pci.photo_collection_id = pc.id
order by s.name, pc.name, si.id
```